# How do the Udacity programers produce those questions, with checkboxes on top of images?

Tags: html

In [here](http://www.udacity.com/view#Course/st101/CourseRev/1/Unit/6001/Nugget/119001) and [here](http://www.udacity.com/view#Course/cs253/CourseRev/apr2012/Unit/20006/Nugget/73002), there are some examples of the quiz questions that are used in Udacity.

How can I achieve such an effect ? (i.e. : how can I build a page where I have an image, and then some form elements over that image ?)

Maybe I could use a table with the image as background. Would that work ? Would it be reliable across browsers ?

Comment: The best way to learn would be to look at the rendered source in your browser using a tool like FireBug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different possibility.

You could place the elements with "absolute" or "relative" position in order to get the element exactly over the image.

You could also draw with a CSS3/HTML5 Canvas.

I think the best thing to do a simple form with an image should be following this [tutorial](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2008/09/15/Turn-postcard-photo-into-a-stunning-comment-form-using-CSS.aspx)

If you manage to create that then you can tweak the CSS code in order to be able to place the card where you want

Comment: @josinalvo were you able to create interactive videos? if yes please let me know. I need to create same. It'll be great help. Hoping for response.

Comment: Just as a note: for reusability etc., we actually position and size everything with % instead of pixels. This means that if the image or container has to shrink, everything shrinks with it.

Answer (score 0):

They just have an image and then absolutely position form elements on top of it.

```
input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Just need to change top and left until the input element is where you want it.  The input elements can sit right on top of the image.